# Problem with changing the language in .bib files

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, greek

I am trying to change the language between entries of my bib file, but it does not recognise greek characters. I am using the **babelbib** package

The main file is as following

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage{babelbib}
\begin{document} .....
\bibliographystyle{babunsrt}
\bibliography{book_bibliography}
\end{document}
```

And my .bib file has entries such as

```
% This is the .bib file
@book{simpleintro,
language={english},
author = {Harvey J. Greenberg},
title={A Simplified Introduction to \LaTeX},
year={2004},
url = {ftp://ftp.tex.ac.uk/ctan%3A/info/simplified-latex/simplified-intro.pdf}
}

@article{seminar,
language={greek},
author = {  Όνομα Συγγραφέα},
title = { Συγγραφή Μαθηματικών Κειμένων με το σύστημα στοιχειοθεσίας \LaTeX},
year={2014},
url = {http://eclass.auth.gr/modules/document/document.php?course=MATH115}
}
```

But what i get after running bibtex and building the file is this
[image]
Can anybody tell me why this happens?

Comment: Your .bib file is encode in utf-8 or other? If I don't pay attention I have problems with éèà and other character. Futhermore I use bibtex8 but I don't know if'll work with greek

Comment: I got no problem when saving the bib file as UTF-8 and also loading `hyperref`. I'd avoid `utf8x`, preferring `utf8` as the option for `inputenc`.

Comment: What you said about saving the bib file with utf-8 encoding sounds interesting. How do i do that?

Comment: @egreg Is this something you'd like to answer?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Added

Answer (score 1):

The `.bib` file, like the main file, should be saved as UTF-8.

In the example I use the `filecontents*` environment in order to make it self-contained; a real document will use a separate `.bib` file.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{simpleintro,
language={english},
author = {Harvey J. Greenberg},
title={A Simplified Introduction to \LaTeX},
year={2004},
url = {ftp://ftp.tex.ac.uk/ctan/info/simplified-latex/simplified-intro.pdf}
}

@article{seminar,
language={greek},
author = {Όνομα Συγγραφέα},
title = {Συγγραφή Μαθηματικών Κειμένων με το σύστημα στοιχειοθεσίας \LaTeX},
year={2014},
url = {http://eclass.auth.gr/modules/document/document.php?course=MATH115}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{babelbib}
\begin{document}

\cite{simpleintro}

\cite{seminar}

\bibliographystyle{babunsrt}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Note the change to the URL (the `%` character is not allowed unless escaped).

[image]